# Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have a problem in creating a template in amazon SES using CLI

```
aws ses create-template --cli-input-json file//s3://ses04/MyTemplatez.json
```

when I call this function in CLI, I am getting the error

```
Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: file//desktop\MyTemplatez.json
```

Please share your suggestion to resolve this

Comment: You're using `file//s3://`, do you mean to fetch the template from S3? You probably have to fetch the file first from S3 with a separate call, then pass it into cli-input-json. Something like `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/key ./MyTemplatez.json`

Answer (score 3):

Use `file://s3://ses04/MyTemplatez.json` instead of `file//s3://ses04/MyTemplatez.json`, the difference is the column sign `:` after `file` keyword.

Comment: If you need to use the file on your disk (Windows):
`file://c:\path\to\file.json`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the file encoding problem.  Save your file in UTF-8 without BOM, then it will work.

> If you use Sublime Text, then go to File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8.

> If you use VS Code, at the bottom bar of VS Code, you'll see the label "UTF-8 with BOM". Click it to open the action bar and select "Save with encoding". Choose UTF-8 and save the file.